# Creating a substitution cypher in Python

Tags: python, string, input, replace, encryption

Hello fellow programmers :)
Just a simple question

Let's say I'm encrypting text.

I have shadow characters for ”a, b, c, d, e” which are ”w, p, z, r, a”

```
original =["a","b","c","d","e"]

shadow = ["w","p","z","r","a"]
```

Then if the user inputs a string

```
user = input("What would you like to input?: ")
```

Let's say the user inputs a string  "a bad cab bed"

How to get it to replace the values of the string with my shadow characters and then print out

(“w pwr zwp par”)

I've just been toiling around for a while and would appreciate some help :D

Answer (score 1):

Conveniently located on your local interwebs.

```
intab = 'aeiou'
outtab = '12345'

s = 'this is string example....wow!!!'

print(s.translate({ord(x): y for (x, y) in zip(intab, outtab)}))
```

Comment: Since he is using `input` and not `raw_input`, I think he is on Python 3.x.  If so, then there is no `string.maketrans`.

Comment: There _is_ [`str.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans). But of course you can't use that when you've named your string `str` and shadowed the class.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to execute the loop explicitly, you might try something like:

```
intab = 'aeiou'
outtab = '12345'

mapper = {key: value for (key, value) in zip(intab, outtab)}

s = 'this is string example....wow!!!'

output = ''.join(mapper.get(char, char) for char in s)
print(output)
```